# TextView won't center in parent RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to center a TextView inside a RelativeLayout, but for some reason  the position of the TextView is not exactly in the center, it's in the center and a little down. This problem occurs when I add the second RelativeLayout, the one with no id.

Here are 2 ways I tried to solve my problem without success:

First:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/minus_one"
   android:layout_width="45dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/lightgrey">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ractangle_visual_feedback_selector"
                android:gravity="center">


            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="-"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Second:

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/minus_one"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/lightgrey">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ractangle_visual_feedback_selector">


                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:textSize="22dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="-"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post screenshot what exactly the behavior currently and what do you need exactly. And what is the `ractangle_visual_feedback_selector` contains ? Post it

Comment: I want to center the TextView, no picture is needed

Answer (score 5):

Change root `Relative Layout` `android:layout_width to "match_parent"`. Remove `android:gravity="center"` from parent `Relative Layout` no needful. Now add the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your `Text View`.

Try this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/minus_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Testing"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

**#.** If your `TextView` height-width is used as `fixed` size or `wrap_content`, then use attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to `TextView` to align it `center` position of its parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="-"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**#.** If your `TextView` height-width is used as `match_parent`, then use attribute `android:gravity="center"` to `TextView` to align it `center` position of its parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="-"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 2):

change the layout_width to match parent

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 2):

try this **android:layout_centerInParent="true"**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="-"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/minus_one"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="-"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your screen shot and layout file code for better understanding.